# Font/Type fill-rule issue with intersecting shapes in InDesign PDFs

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, pdf, fill, error

With some fonts in InDesign (in this case, [HEX Franklin](https://www.futurefonts.xyz/hex/hex-franklin)), the **PDFs** that are exported show weird rendering issues (see screenshot). I tried reading up on this, but couldn't find a clear answer as to why this is happening, or what to do about it. InDesign itself displays the type correctly.

[image: image showing rendering problem on intersecting shapes in a font, HEX Franklin]

### My findings so far

- This seems to be caused by the [even–odd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule) fill rule, which can show overlapping areas of a polygon as transparent.
  (vs. [Nonzero winding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule), which fills those areas, as desired)
- Only a few fonts have this issue, not all
- When the type is converted to outlines, everything is fine
- It may be a *display* problem of macOS, not an error inside the PDF, according to [EvenOddTT](http://twardoch.github.io/test-fonts/varia/160413-EvenOddTT/), [danielchooper](https://twitter.com/danielchooper/status/1524895377958359051) and a discussion on the [fonttools Github](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools/issues/2059)

Is there a setting in InDesign (CC 2022) I can use to fix this? I'd like to keep my type intact if possible. Changing the font files themselves is also unrealistic, I fear.

I'm grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may be the font file itself. 30+years of work and thousands upon thousands of fonts exported to PDF (using a Mac).. never seen this issue. But, I don't recall ever using a HEX foundry font or "FutureFonts". It is hard to imagine a $200 font would show this issue.

Comment: I have also for example encountered the same thing with [Roslindale](https://djr.com/roslindale/) (Variable), a typeface by David Jonathan Ross. I suspect it's not a case of bad font file generation, rather a *display* error in macOS. If I display the same file in Acrobat, it renders fine! If I upload it to eg. Google Drive, the preview there renders fine as well.

Comment: What do you mean "display error"? If it renders fine in Acrobat.. how *else* is it being displayed showing the error?? -- Your question *specifically states* "PDFs that are exported show weird rendering issues" Aren't you seeing the error in Acrobat?

Comment: Are you using Preview to view PDFS? **That** can *entirely* be the issue. Preview is a piece of...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to narrow down when this is happening. Yes, I view many PDFs in Preview, since I have not been burned by it for a long time. I should have checked Acrobat sooner. Also, I'm on macOS Catalina (10.15), which seems to have introduced quite a few bugs related to OS-level text rendering. It may be a question better suited for the Apple StackExchange.

Comment: Yup. I'd wager Preview is the issue. Preview has *always* failed in some respects. It would not be the least surprising if it has a rending issue with some font construction methods. And it's not that you will "get burned" by Preview, rather you simply don't know what errors may be present until they are *glaring*. I also tend to avoid the bleeding edge MacOS. But that's me... Apple designs for the high school student any more and they rarely test adequately for higher-end professional use. It's not until four or five (or more) x.x.x releases that many bugs are worked out.